# Exit an application on button click in iPhone using PhoneGap

Tags: ios, cordova, dojo, exit

I'm using PhoneGap in Xcode. The problem is that I want to quit application when user clicks on Logout button. How can this be achieved?

[image: The code is displayed in below screenshot]

Is there any alertnative that objective-c code can be used to quit application?

[image]

Comment: that goes agains the Apple HIG

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't have to launch `open` using `NSTask`... `open` just calls into [Launch Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html), some of whose functionality is directly available from [NSWorkspace](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
2. To quit, you just call `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] terminate:nil]`. See [`NSApplication` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: But how can this be written in an HTML file? Since everything in PhoneGap is in HTML/Dojo.

Answer (score 0):

You're technically not supposed to exit the application if you're planning to submit your App to the App Store.
See here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1561.html

Perhaps, you should bring the user back to some sort of login/landing page instead.